# Adding custom properties to Fault entity

Tags: c#, microservices, masstransit

I'm wondering is it possible to configure additional property to Fault message? I have my own exception type which is defined as follows:

```
public class DomainException : Exception 
{
  public string Code { get; private set; } 
 ...
}
```

I have generic consumer which handles all faults that occured, but I don't have any idea, how I could get Code property from Fault entity. 
The Fault entity holds informations about type of exception which was thrown, about correlated message, but unfortunately the Code property is missing.

Is it possible to pass this information to Fault consumer? Maybe inside headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're at that level of business logic in your exception, it would be recommended that you catch the exception yourself, and publish your own domain fault event that is relevant to your business context. For instance, you could define your own DomainFault type:

```
public interface DomainFault : 
    Fault
{
    string Code { get; }
}
```

Then, you could publish it yourself using a try/catch handler in your consumer, or you could create a filter for the consumer pipeline to use it with multiple consumers.

Comment: Ok I see. I have one more question - why mass transit always creates at least two exchanges. I have message CreateOrder in namespace Commands. Why MassTransit creates two exchanges where the first one is Commands.CreateOrder?

Comment: Because MassTransit supports polymorphic messaging on RabbitMQ, where you can subscribe to an interface and any type published that implements the interface will be delivered to the consumer as that interface type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but.. I have one little question. Is it possible to do that, whenever I send any command from my api to bus, it will be consumed by two consumers? 
The first consumer is the generic command consumer(in service a), and the second is consumer specyfict to this particular command(in service b)?